# Displaying button at the end of onboarding flow on swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm implementing an onboarding flow, using a container. Doing that, I would like the user to be able to use a "Next" button only when the last page of the flow has been displayed.

Currently, the button is displayed at the same time the last page is about to be displayed (even if only the gesture is detected but the page remains on the same one, the button is displayed. I mean that I have 3 pages and if I do like I would swap, if I stay on the second page, the button is displayed).

Here is my class:

```
class OnboardingViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    enum PageViews: String {
        case firstPV
        case secondPV
        case thirdPV
    }

    var skipBtn: UIButton!
    var nextIndex: Int!

    fileprivate lazy var orderedViewController: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.getViewController(withIdentifier: PageViews.firstPV.rawValue),
                self.getViewController(withIdentifier: PageViews.secondPV.rawValue),
                self.getViewController(withIdentifier: PageViews.thirdPV.rawValue)]
    }()

    fileprivate func getViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController
    {
        return (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier))!
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewController.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
        enableSkipBtn(enabling: false)
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }
        guard orderedViewController.count > previousIndex else { return nil }
        return orderedViewController[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewController.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        guard nextIndex < orderedViewController.count else { return nil }
        guard orderedViewController.count > nextIndex else { return nil }
        if nextIndex == orderedViewController.count - 1 {
            enableSkipBtn(enabling: true)
        }

        return orderedViewController[nextIndex]
    }

    func presentationCount(for: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return orderedViewController.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        if let firstVC = orderedViewController.first {
            setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            nextIndex = 0
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods
    func enableSkipBtn(enabling: Bool) {
        skipBtn.isEnabled = enabling
        skipBtn.isHidden = !enabling
    }

}
```

I'm using the viewControllerAfter function to hide or display my button, but it's not doing what I would like to.

If you need more details, just ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this Delegate Method:

```
class OnboardingViewController: UIPageViewController, 
    UIPageViewControllerDataSource, 
    UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    /* more code */

    // UIPageViewControllerDelegate Methods
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, 
        didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
        previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
        transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

        if completed {
            if nextIndex == 3 {
                enableSkipBtn(true)
            } else {
                enableSkipBtn(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it today but I'm facing something weird, my next and previous index are not going as I would like to, so I think it could solve my problem, but try to make it working first. To explain, my nextIndex is at max only when I go back from the last view to the previous one. So the button will be displayed only if I keep on swaping after last page or if I go back.

Comment: I will put your answer as correct, since it's correctly updating things at the end of the animation. I just have to figure out which index and which moment are the right ones (inside your function then).